# Sticky navbar (hcSticky) is under bootstrap carousel images when scrolled over

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, hcsticky

You can see the issue very clearly in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/7FJvf/13/).

I have a sticky bootstrap navbar, made sticky with [hcSticky](http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/).

When you scroll down, when you go by the images of the bootstrap carousel, theese are over the navbar and it should be the other way round.

The sticky navbar is instantiated the usual way:

```
$("#thenav").hcSticky();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple problem with the `z-index`.

Simply add:

```
#thenav{
    z-index:1;
}
```

And the issue should be solved, see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/7FJvf/14/).

Comment: It is a simple issue but I figured it out while writing the question so I answered it myself since it might be helpful for someone in the future.